# How to send PHPMailer that retrieve email template from database and insert variable into template

Tags: sql, phpmailer

I'm trying to retrieve a email template from my database to my PHPMailer body. The variables`$title` and `$name` are to put inside my email template so the variables are displayed together with the template. Is there any suggestions of doing it?

Here is my database of the template:
[image: db]
Below is the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['issue']))
    {
        ...
        $username = $_POST['studentname'];
        $bookid = $_POST['bookdetails'];

        //perform multi query to retrieve data
        $sql= "SELECT option_value FROM settings WHERE option_name = 'email_temp_issue';";
        $sql .="SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = '$bookid';";
        $sql .="SELECT fullName from students WHERE email = '$username'";
        $sql_run = mysqli_multi_query($connection,$sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_run)>0)
        {
            foreach ($sql_run as $row)
            {
                $email_template = $row['option_value']; //retrieve email template 
                $title = $row['title']; //variable to put in email template
                $name = $row['fullName']; //variable to put in email template 
            }
        }//NOT SURE IF I RETRIEVE IT RIGHT..

        $mail->Body = "$email_template"; //load template to email body



        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "<script>alert('Error while sending Email.')</script>";
            var_dump($mail);
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Email sent successfully')</script>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/OWASP_Top_Ten_2017/Top_10-2017_A1-Injection), so you should mitigate that as a matter of urgency.

To send to a list from a database, base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

PHPMailer doesn't care how you create your message body, so you can do simple string substitutions using your examples:

```
$mail->Body = str_replace(['{name}', '{title}'], [$name, $title], $email_template);
```

or something more complex using a template engine like Smarty or Twig if it's appropriate.